# How to add action to a subviews Attributes Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I am relatively new to Swift and I would like to add a series of action to my custom `UIView` Button

Here's the code but when ever I press the button I get this error.

Please tell me the best practice for modelling this.

```
class CameraView: UIView {

    var cameraButton : UIButton?

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        cameraButton = UIButton()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }


    func setButton(button : UIButton){
        self.cameraButton = button
    }


    func setUpMyView(){
        self.cameraButton = UIButton()
        self.cameraButton?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.cameraButton?.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.cameraButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.cameraButton?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        self.addSubview(cameraButton!)
    }

}


ViewController.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cameraView : CameraView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cameraView = CameraView()

        cameraView?.cameraButton?.addTarget(self, action: "pressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view = cameraView

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func pressed(sender : AnyObject!){
        print("Button Pressed")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Another Alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true , completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Error

```
2016-01-16 14:00:42.023 TPProject[4194:1442964] -[TPProject.ViewController pressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125655a30
2016-01-16 14:00:42.028 TPProject[4194:1442964] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TPProject.ViewController pressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125655a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183d39900 0x1833a7f80 0x183d4061c 0x183d3d5b8 0x183c4168c 0x188a63e50 0x188a63dcc 0x188a4ba88 0x188a636e4 0x188a63314 0x188a5be30 0x188a2c4cc 0x188a2a794 0x183cf0efc 0x183cf0990 0x183cee690 0x183c1d680 0x18512c088 0x188a94d90 0x1000adf64 0x1837be8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I had to add a : to action

from this Line

```
cameraView?.cameraButton?.addTarget(self, action: "pressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

to

```
cameraView?.cameraButton?.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: On a side note, there is no need to subclass UIView for this - have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/. You're not overriding any of the UIView's or UIButton's  methods so you just create a UIButton in your ViewController and configure it in ViewDidLoad() or LoadView(). If you're going to be reusing the look of the button you can create a new method for UIButton in a UIButtonExtension.swift file - more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html.